# Why does jom hide gcc warnings in QtCreator?

Tags: gcc, qt-creator

In my Windows QtCreator project I use jom for compiling C++ with several cores. The problem is, that when jom is activated, not all warnings are displayed in the build problem tab.
In the compilation tab, the warnings that are not displayed are shown in black, while all warnings that actually show up in the build problem tab are printed in red. 
On a QT site, I read that red text means standard error, while black text means standard out.

So, why is jom shifting some warnings from stderr to stdout?

The type of the warning doesn't seem to matter, some unused parameter warnings go to stdout some go to stderr. 
I also tried to disable jom, then all warnings are correctly displayed in the build-problems tab (and are printed in red text in compilation tab)

Cheers, and thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

We have found the same problem, and as a temporary solution we've reverted back to jom 1.0.08 (which is the lastest version of Jom which still works correctly).

You can download Jom 1.0.08 from ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/jom/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue with Jom version 1.0.11. 
I changed to the latest version (1.0.13), now the warnings and erros are displayed in tje 'build-problems'-tab again.